# What kind of special effect did Alfred Hitchcock use in this scene for "The Lady Vanishes"?

Tags: effects, the-lady-vanishes

The shot from *The Lady Vanishes* I am talking about is when Iris looks back to say goodbye to her friends after getting clonk on the head. She was feeling dizzy when she got on the train.

[image: black-and-white blurry image of a woman]

Can you let me know the actual name of this effect or how Alfred Hitchcock shot this? This is for my research project. I thought it was interesting since I do not see this in modern films. Does anyone know if Alfred Hitchcock was the first person to use this in movies as a transition?

Comment: @Giacomo1968: If one uses an optical or digital post-production effect, or using a physical or chemical post-production effect on a copy of the film, one will end up with a copy of the film that has the effect along with an original that doesn't.  If the effect doesn't turn out as desired, one can re-use the original film and apply the effect differently without having to re-shoot the actors.  By contrast, if anything goes wrong when using in-camera effects, or using chemical or physical effects on the original camera film, it will be necessary to re-shoot the scene from scratch.

Comment: These days, of course, you composite pseudo-live in digital 'video' whilst shooting film on a splitter, so you can test what you'll get post-pro without touching the master. I do think the old kaleidoscope effect would be a bit simplistic for a modern audience, though; & you could easily do it in post if you ever felt the need ;)

Comment: He time travelled forward to 1975 and used Queen's setup for Bohemian Rhapsody.

Comment: Note on Giacomo's first comment; if you use the right lighting and a toilet paper tube in front of your cell phone camera, you can take a selfie that looks like your face is on the moon.  It's a pretty funny effect.

Comment: I've always assumed that shots like these were done with kaleidoscopes.

Comment: @RBarryYoung normal kaleidoscopes have mirrors, so some of the images would be flipped

Answer (score 61):

It's done using a prismatic kaleidoscope filter over the lens, known as a multi-image filter.

They were very popular in the 60s & 70s for 'flower power/drugs/music video' type shots, often rotating the filter as the camera rolled, to make it even more 'dreamy'.
Their popularity declined in later years - same as anything else, it just became passé, "been there, done that, worn the t-shirt out".

I have no idea who may have been first to use such a filter.

See this question & answer at our Photography sister site - [What is this physical filter, shaped like a shallow pyramid?](https://photo.stackexchange.com/questions/88215/what-is-this-physical-filter-shaped-like-a-shallow-pyramid/88217#88217) - elements copied below…

This is a small version for a stills camera, but they could be made in any size.

[image: filter front view]
[image: filter side view]

[image]

Comment: That example looks OK, but many were prone to colour fringing on all but the central sharp image as the segments are like very weak prisms.  Not a problem in B&W of course, except that it adds to the softening of the outer images

Comment: Sure, but that's pretty much in the definition of prism ;) [goes to look at his Dark Side of the Moon album cover… yup :P

Comment: Presumably they choose the material for low dispersion, while your typical rainbow prism is chosen for high dispersion. But they can't get zero dispersion